# Is it safe to use field inside and outside synchronized block?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, resharper

**Background**

Our app sends emails which are queued in a database table.  We've had some instances of duplicate emails being sent, so I'm implementing a lock to prevent multiple threads from sending emails simultaneously.

ReSharper is warning me that:

> the field is sometimes used inside synchronized block and sometimes
>   used without synchronization

**Question**

Why is ReSharper telling me this, and why might I be worried about it?

**Code**

Here's my (abridged) code:

```
private readonly IMailQueueRepository _mailQueueRepository = new MailQueueRepository();
private static object _messageQueueLock = new object();

public void SendAllQueuedMessages(IPrincipal caller)
{
    lock (_messageQueueLock) // Prevent concurrent callers
    {
        var message = _mailQueueRepository.GetUnsentMessage();
        while (message != null)
        {
            SendQueuedMessage(message);
            message = _mailQueueRepository.GetUnsentMessage();
        }
    }
}

public void SendQueuedMessage(IMessage message)
{
    // I get the ReSharper warning here on _mailQueueRepository
    var messageAttachments = _mailQueueRepository.GetMessageAttachments(message.Id);
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem scenario :

> We've had some instances of duplicate emails being sent, so I'm implementing a lock to prevent multiple threads from sending emails simultaneously.

So you are using `Lock()` to prevent this happening, that means you need to synchronize threads accessing a common resource which in this case  `_mailQueueRepository`

But again in the same code you use `_mailQueueRepository` without a `Lock`

```
 // I get the ReSharper warning here on _mailQueueRepository
    var messageAttachments = _mailQueueRepository.GetMessageAttachments(message.Id); // <== Accessed without a lock
```

So it's a warning to tell that your valuable resource is accessed in two different forms : one as `synchronized`(thread safe) and other `non-synchronized`(non thread safe).

And it's a warning that let **you** **know**(or let you identify) issues that could arise from this contradictory usage of the resource `_mailQueueRepository`. Choice is yours to either make all usages of `_mailQueueRepository` `synchronized` (use with a `lock` and warning will be gone) or manage not to run for race conditions.

Additionally you might consider to re-structure the codes in such a way that your `SendQueuedMessage()` is called with parameters which are extracted from `_mailQueueRepository` avoiding mix usage.

Comment: Actually, it's the method which reads the queue and sends emails - not the repository itself - that I'm trying to prevent concurrent access to.  I _want_ threads to be able to write to the repository while one thread is reading emails and sending them.  But I guess ReSharper can't tell that, so it warns me.  _I_ know that I'm actually fine with unsynchronized access to that resource, so I guess I'm safe to ignore the warning?

Comment: @OutstandingBill - From resharper : "Warnings
In addition to compiler errors and warnings, ReSharper displays its own warnings that don't prevent your code from compiling but may nevertheless represent serious coding inefficiencies". Resharper is intelligence enough to say contradictory usage but you are the one know what actual usage is.  If you are confirmed to use the resource well managed you could ignore the warning :)

Comment: @OutstandingBill  Additionally you might be interested in re-tructuring the method to take parameters extracted from the field , rather than using it in mix context

Comment: What exactly does `you might be interested in re-structuring the method to take parameters extracted from the field` mean?

Answer (score 7):

ReSharper can not tell (or guarantee) that `SendQueuedMessage()` is only called from within a synchronized block. So as far as it is concerned, other code might call `SendQueuedMessage()` without synchronization, and `_mailQueueRepository` is being used in `SendQueuedMessage()`.

If you are sure that no other code (inside or outside the containing class) calls this method, or you've made sure all calls from within the class to `SendQueuedMessage()` are also synchronized *using the same lock object*, you're ok. If no other code outside your class actually needs this method, I would suggest you make it private.